# Inline подсказка при вводе команды боту telegram

Tags: telegram-bot

Здравствуйте, реализовал своему боту inline-встраиваемость, при использовании @%bot_name%. Но никак не могу понять, как реализовать нечто подобное:[image: команды для бота]

Т.е. нужно при вводе пользователем части команды сразу выводить ему возможные варианты. Использую python и модули telebot с pyTelegramBotAPI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это список команд, *Inline mode* к этому не имеет отношения. Задать команды можно с помощью **@BotFather** --> **/mybots** --> <kbd>Your_Bot_Name</kbd> --> <kbd>Edit bot</kbd> --> <kbd>Edit commands</kbd>

---

[Telegram Bot API - Commands](https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands)

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с тем же вопросом и вижу что уже неактуальный топик. Но просто оставлю это здесь:

- включить через ОтецБот'а BotSettins -> Inline Mode -> "Turn on"
- о реализация в боте, не плохой лессон: https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/docs/lesson_07/

Answer (score 0):

Включи [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather), введи /setcommands, выбери своего бота(если их несколько), потом в стиле
command1 - Описание
command2 - Описание
...

запиши все команды(если надо сделать пусты, введи /empty) и отправь боту. Он должен отправить "Success! Command list updated. /help"
Актуально на 2023!