# Отображение списка команд в Telegram боте

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Здраствуйте.

Как реализовать появление списка доступных команд при наборе `/` в Telegram боте (как на первой картинке).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форуме нашел такие же вопросы как у меня, но им по 2 года и может быть что то изменилось, и стало можно задавать список не только у BotFather, если все также, то можно закрывать.

1. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749298/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749298/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-telegram)
2. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702167/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702167/inline-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-telegram)

---

Добавить команды, добавил, что читал:

1. https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands
2. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods

Пишу на `php` использую [эту библиотеку](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs). А [вот тут](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs/commands-system) про команды.

Получилось следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если теперь можно добавить список в коде подскажите как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Увы, сейчас всё так же. Как более удобная альтернатива - кнопки

Comment: @Ein очень жаль. Подскажите как закрыть